# z3 and muZ for computing program invariants

Tags: z3

I'm trying to play with the fixpoint solver of z3 (muZ), in order to find program invariants. However, at some point, the query answers unsat but I don't figure out why, since the code is reachable :

```
(declare-rel b1 (Int) interval_relation bound_relation)
(declare-rel b2 (Int) interval_relation bound_relation)
(declare-rel b3 (Int Int) interval_relation bound_relation)
(declare-rel b4 (Int Int) interval_relation bound_relation)
(declare-rel b5 (Int Int) interval_relation bound_relation)
(declare-rel b6 (Int) interval_relation bound_relation)

(declare-var i Int)
(declare-var j Int)

(rule (b1 0))
(rule (=> (and (b1 i) (< i 50)) (b2 i)))
(rule (=> (b2 i) (b3 i 0)))
(rule (=> (and (b3 i j) (< j 50)) (b4 i j)))
(rule (=> (b4 i j) (b3 (+ i 1) (+ j 1))))
(rule (=> (and (b3 i j) (>= j 50)) (b5 i j)))
(rule (=> (b5 i j) (b1 (+ 1 (- i j)))))
(rule (=> (and (b1 i) (>= i 50)) (b6 i)))

(query (b3 i j)
  :compile-with-widening true
  :unbound-compressor false
  :engine datalog
  :print-answer true
)
 ; answers unsat

(query (b4 i j)
  :compile-with-widening true
  :unbound-compressor false
  :engine datalog
  :print-answer true
)
; answers sat
; (and (<= 0 (:var 1)) (<= (:var 1) 49))
; this invariant is correct

; corresponding C program:
; int f() {
;   int i = 0;
;   int j = 0;
; 
;   while (i < 50) {  // b1
;       j = 0;
;       while (j < 50) {  // b3
;           i++;
;           j++;
;       }
;       i = i-j+1;
;   }
;   return i;
; }
```

Can someone explain me why it returns "unsat" ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: For future readers: this code is out of date, and no longer compiles in z3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the current release of Z3 (the muZ part).
It affects the datalog engine when applied with 
the interval and bounds domains.
It is fixed in the local (unstable) branch now.
The fix will be available in the next release.